ESP32 Event Handling Button Press
Is there a reasonably easy way to create an event driven button press?  I am using ESP-WROOM-32 ESP32 ESP-32S WiFi + Bluetooth Dev Board and Arduino IDE.  I know that the loop speed is really fast but I'm planning on having the project do some other tasks while it's waiting for the button to be pushed.  Think of it as a slap button response (so the button will be pressed very momentarily).  Below is a simple example of my current code ... I'd like to replace the recursive loop with an event driven version so that with everything else going on, it won't run the risk of missing a really quick button slap.
// BUTTON SENSING INPUT
const int btnInputPin1 = 12;

// BUTTON LED OUTPUT
const int ledOutputPin1 = 25;

// BUTTON LED STATUS
bool ledStatus1 = false;

void setup() {
    // Set LED pin to output
    pinMode(ledOutputPin1, OUTPUT);
    
    // Set BUTTON pin to input
    pinMode(btnInputPin1, INPUT); 

    // Initially turn ON LED 
    digitalWrite(ledOutputPin1, HIGH);
    ledStatus1 = true; 
}

void loop() {
    if ((digitalRead(btnInputPin1) == HIGH) && (ledStatus1 == true)) {
        digitalWrite(ledOutputPin1, LOW);
        ledStatus1 = false;
    }
}


Look at the code associated with the arduino button libraries for ideas.

The answer to your question is interrupts. That's a hardware feature to catch and process events which happen very quickly. In your specific case you're interested in GPIO interrupts and a nice article about them is here: https://lastminuteengineers.com/handling-esp32-gpio-interrupts-tutorial/
